# How do I create a user with a random password and store it to a file using puppet

Tags: puppet

I want to create a user for a service (postgres, rabbitmq...) using a random generated password. This password should then be written to a file on the host. This file, containing env vars is then used by an application to connect to those services.

I don't want to store these passwords elsewhere.

```
postgresql::server::db { $name:
  user     => $name,
  password => postgresql_password($name, random_password(10)),
}
```

Then i want to insert this password in the form PG_PASS='the same password' into a config file but the whole thing should happen only if the user is not already present.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## In pure Puppet

A trick is to define a custom type somehow like :

```
define authfile($length=24,$template,$path) {
  $passwordfile = "/etc/puppet/private/${::hostname}/${::title}"
  $password = file($passwordfile,'/dev/null')
  @@exec { "generate-${title}":
    command => "openssl rand -hex -out '$passwordfile' 24",
    creates => $passwordfile,
    tag     => 'generated_password'
  }
  file { $path:
    content => template($template);
  }
}
```

And on your puppetmaster, have something like :

```
Exec<|| tag = 'generated_password' ||>
```

You can then pass in the `$template` variable the name of a template that will have the variable `$password` available. You will need to be careful about how these `authfile` types are defined (as it creates files on the puppetmaster, you will want to take care of malicious facts), and you will need to run puppet once on the host (so that the exported resources is created), once on the puppetmaster (so that the secret file is generated), then once again on the host (so that the secret file is read) for it to work.

## With a custom function

Another solution is to write a custom function, `random_password`, that will use the fqdn and sign it with a secret that is stored on the puppetmaster (using a HMAC) to seed the password. That way you will have a password that can't be guessed without getting the secret, and no extra puppet roundtrips.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried it myself yet. But [trocla](https://github.com/duritong/trocla) looks exactly like what you're looking for. [Here's a little intro](https://tech.immerda.ch/2011/12/trocla-get-hashed-passwords-out-of-puppet-manifests/).

EDIT: After having now tried out trocla I can tell you that it works like a charm :-)
You need to have the [trocla module](https://github.com/duritong/puppet-trocla) installed to use it from puppet.